# Unable to access FOR...IN in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to access the object in `[]` JSON literal as an array using `FOR...IN`. But iterating through `FOR...IN` gives the object `x` `undefined`. Please see the code below.

```
var myJSONObject = [
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
];

for (var x in myJSONObject) {
    alert(x['method']);
}
```

**You may test the code online here @ [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/imoyu4/edit)**

Regards,
Munim

Comment: That's not a JSON array, it's a Javascript array: JSON is merely a notation (JavaScript Object Notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for (var x in myJSONObject) {
    alert( myJSONObject[x]['method'] );
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! Can you please explain? I see `x` as `undefined` and how does `myJSONObject[x]` works?

Comment: Don't use `for … in` to iterate over an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description

Comment: `x` in this case, is an identifier, not the actual element. So, in your first iteration, `x` would be equal to `0`. However, as mentioned by Marcel, when iterating over arrays, you should be using a standard `for` loop.

Comment: Everyone is right when they say, "for...in" is bad for a numerically indexed array. I simply copied the example you used and added the correction.

Comment: in for x in y, the x value represents a contained property name.  In an array, that will mostly be a number, in a dynamic object it can be any type of primitive (string, number, boolean, etc). Since you are looking for the VALUES associated with those names, you look up the values through array notation: y[ x ].  The value myJSONObject[x] has a method property.  myJSONObject does not.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't iterate over an array using [`for … in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description):

> Although it may be tempting to use
>   this as a way to iterate over an
>   Array, this is a bad idea. The
>   for...in statement iterates over
>   user-defined properties in addition to
>   the array elements, so if you modify
>   the array's non-integer or
>   non-positive properties (e.g. by
>   adding a "foo" property to it or even
>   by adding a method or property to
>   Array.prototype), the for...in 
>   statement will return the name of your
>   user-defined properties in addition to
>   the numeric indexes. Also, because
>   order of iteration is arbitrary,
>   iterating over an array may not visit
>   elements in numeric order. Thus it is
>   better to use a traditional for loop
>   with a numeric index when iterating
>   over arrays.

Just loop through your array this way:

```
for (var i = 0, length = myJSONObject.length; i < length; i++) {
    alert(myJSONObject[i].method);
}
```

See [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/imoyu4/2/edit).

Answer (score 0):

The for .. in syntax gives you the keys of the iterated object, not the values. Thus, you have to do the following:

```
for (var idx in myJSONObject) {
    alert(myJSONObject[idx]['method']);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for … in` to iterate over an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description